# Python - Does Kivy implements activities in the Android apps?

Tags: android, python, kivy

As we all know, when developing an Android app in native Java, we use activities. I was wondering that, in developing Android apps in Python(with Kivy), **does Kivy implements activities** for the apps in itself or not? because I don't see any activity implementation on the sample codes.

If it doesn't implement activities, Do we lose performance or any functionality in the application compared to coding in native Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you can use Activities (starting them using pyjnius), but not really define them, at least, it's not usually the way one work with kivy.

Kivy doesn't adjust its way of working for targetted platform, it uses its own systems, and make them work there. For what i know the advantages of separating Activities on android is just a way to make your code more neatly organized, and doesn't imply performance changes. It can allow you to start your app in various ways (from a share, for example) but you can do that with p4a/buildozer too, by dispatching messages about the intent, if you need to. With kivy, you'll organise your code like you would do for any python project, using modules.

Comment: Thank you for your response, can you introduce me some resource about that?  are you sure that `the advantages of separating Activities on android is just a way to make your code more neatly organized` ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html i just re-read that, and to me the loosely-connected part is the point, of course, considering it's different screens, the back button point applies, but unless you want an app to be able to start your kivy app directly to a screen, and that the back button would go to the previous -app- activity, the current mecanism should be enough, you can always bind the back button to go to the previous screen in your kivy app (adding an history to ScreenManager) or cancel the current action.

Comment: Thank you, I searched everywhere to get the answer, but I failed. until now ... :)

Answer (score 1):

Kivy is a great tool for developing Android Apps. The best advantage of using Kivy is that it is cross platform and the same project can be used to publish apps on mutti-platforms.

However , it has some performance related disadvantages(as do most cross-platform tools like unity , cocos etc). If you're developing only for Android , I'd suggest taking a look into development tools which use Java. This will help create a smaller APK file which in turn helps in better user retention.

I guess you are real loyal fan of Python, but I have to tell you about its advantage and disadvantage.

Advantages

1. Pure python and its almightiness is in your hand.
2. Relatively simple to deploy with buildozer without any need to dive too deep into the details of particular platform.
3. You can run your app on desktop also, so there is no need to install some extra emulators/VMs to get it work

Disadvantages

1. Not that much information in Internet, even on stackoverflow
2. Pretty messy documentation
3. No obvious way to test the application
4. Not obvious machanisms of placing widgets, especially in built in layouts, which causes situations like: you want place widget in the center of it's parent, but kivy places it anywhere but not where you want it to be.
5. Official examples are quite ugly, so you may get false vision of how your application could look like.

Comment: No, I'm not a fan of Python, I am comparing it with Java, I read many articles about advantages and disadvantages, something I didn't find, is using or not using  activities. Thank you for the answer, but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: While i can agree with some of this answer, i'll have to disagree with almost all of the disavantage section: The docs could see some help, but we do think most of what's needed is in there. The point about layouts shows there is certainly a misunderstanding of how they work. Examples are there to show features, there are complete apps to show what you can do for theming. The point about the minimal 7mb size would have found its place in there, but i'm not sure how relevant it is these days. 500kb apps are gone anyway.